# GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory() Qt

Tags: windows, qt, include

Well, actually this is easy to do in Visual Studio 2010. I include windows.h, and done. But i'm trying to do this in Qt, however no success. I included windows.h but still GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory() isn't defined.

Comment: Maybe it is a *C* function, and you need some `extern "C"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory` function isn't included in current MinGw `windows.h` header. But you can declare it yourself:

```
extern "C"
WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory (PULONGLONG );
```

Then, liking with `kernel32` allows you to use it:

```
g++ source.cpp -lkrenel32
```